# Community Page Variation Based on Contact Record Field

Tags: community, napili, checkbox

I would like to make a Community page variation be visible based on the status of a checkbox on users' contact records.  Is this possible?  Thank you.

Comment: That is not how page variations work, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am happy to say that I got the page variation to display based on the value of a Contact record field.  I accomplished this by creating a formula field on the User object that references the field in the Contact record.  The field in the Contact record is a checkbox, but I made my formula field have a formula 
if (gc_rep__c,"True","False").  The Page Variation audience checks to see if the formula field is equal to the string True.  This seems to work very nicely.